# Wildfly Swarm: Environment specific configuration of Keycloak Backend

Tags: devops, keycloak, wildfly-swarm

Given is a JavaEE application on wildfly that uses keycloak as authentication backend, configured in project-stages.yml:

```
swarm:
  deployment:
    my.app.war:
      web:
        login-config:
          auth-method: KEYCLOAK
```

The application will be deployed in different environments using a Gitlab-CD-Pipeline. Therefore keycloak specifics must be configured per environment.

By now the only working configuration that I found is adding a keycloak.json like (the same file in every environment):

```
{
  "realm": "helsinki",
  "bearer-only": true,
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8180/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "backend" 
}
```

According to the [Wildfly-Swarm Documentation](https://reference.wildfly-swarm.io/fractions/keycloak.html) it should be possible to configure keycloak in project-stages.yml like:

```
swarm:      
  keycloak:
    secure-deployments:
      my-deployment:
        realm: keycloakrealmname
        bearer-only: true
        ssl-required: external
        resource: keycloakresource
        auth-server-url: http://localhost:8180/auth
```

But when I deploy the application, no configuration is read:

```
2018-03-08 06:29:03,540 DEBUG [org.keycloak.adapters.undertow.KeycloakServletExtension] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 12) KeycloakServletException initialization
2018-03-08 06:29:03,540 DEBUG [org.keycloak.adapters.undertow.KeycloakServletExtension] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 12) using /WEB-INF/keycloak.json
2018-03-08 06:29:03,542 WARN  [org.keycloak.adapters.undertow.KeycloakServletExtension] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 12) No adapter configuration.  Keycloak is unconfigured and will deny all requests.
2018-03-08 06:29:03,545 DEBUG [org.keycloak.adapters.undertow.KeycloakServletExtension] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 12) Keycloak is using a per-deployment configuration.
```

If you take a look at the [source](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/adapters/oidc/undertow/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/undertow/KeycloakServletExtension.java) of the above class, it looks like the only way to get around is to provide a KeycloakConfigResolver. Does Wildfly-Swarm provide a resolver that reads the project-stages.yml?

How can I configure environment-specific auth-server-urls?

A workaround would be to have different keycloak.json-Files, but I would rather use the project-stages.yml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a small WildFly Swarm project which configures Keycloak exclusively  via `project-defaults.yml` here: https://github.com/Ladicek/swarm-test-suite/tree/master/wildfly/keycloak

From the snippets you post, the only thing that looks wrong is this:

```
swarm:      
  keycloak:
    secure-deployments:
      my-deployment:
```

The `my-deployment` name needs to be the actual name of the deployment, same as what you have in

```
swarm:
  deployment:
    my.app.war:
```

If you already have that, then I'm afraid I'd have to start speculating: which WildFly Swarm version you use? Which Keycloak version?

Comment: Thanks Ladicek, that was exactly what I was missing!

Answer (score 0):

Also you could specify the swarm.keycloak.json.path property in your yml: 
`swarm:
  keycloak:
    json:
      path: path-to-keycloak-config-files-folder/keycloak-prod.json`

and you can dynamically select a yml file config during startup of the application with the `-Dswarm.project.stage` option.

Further references:

- cheat sheet: http://design.jboss.org/redhatdeveloper/marketing/wildfly_swarm_cheatsheet/cheat_sheet/images/wildfly_swarm_cheat_sheet_r1v1.pdf
- using multiple swarm project stages (profiles) example: https://github.com/thorntail/thorntail/tree/master/testsuite/testsuite-project-stages/src/test/resources
- https://docs.thorntail.io/2018.1.0/#_keycloak